# How do I rebuild a C# ANTLR parser without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr

I'm trying to poke around in the Boo compiler a little.  Unfortunately, the parser is generated by ANTLR.  I've edited the grammar file that the parser is generated from, but I just can't figure out how to perform the next step: actually generating the parser.

Apparently the preferred way to use ANTLR to generate a parser is with the ANTLRWorks IDE... unless you're using the C# output target, because that's *special*.  I tried it anyway, and it did nothing but give me errors saying "This command is not valid in legacy mode."  Apparently there's a new version of ANTLR out since the Boo compiler was written, and there are some backwards compatibility issues there... or something.  Not sure exactly.

So I looked up the C# target.  That wants to be installed as a plugin in Visual Studio.  Only problem is, I have SharpDevelop, which doesn't work with VS plugins, and I'm not about to go shell out hundreds of dollars for a non-Express edition of Visual Studio so I can use an open-source tool to build an open-source parser!

There has to be a simple way to do this; I'm just not seeing it.  How do I generate a C# parser with ANTLR, without Visual Studio?

Comment: What version of ANTLR/ANTLRWorks are you using? I am using both to generate c# code.

Comment: @Patrick: I'm using the most recent version of ANTLRWorks (just downloaded it) and it appears to have backwards-compatibility issues.

Comment: I think so. I have seen that too. Can you use a previous version of ANTLR? Optionally, we use ant for our build process, and there is a library that integrates. It might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANTLR plugin for Visual Studio only provides editor features and simplified ability to add new grammars to a project. It does not perform any code generation itself.

The C# targets for both ANTLR 3 and ANTLR 4 are seamlessly integrated with MSBuild. By design, the target does not support command line generation of parsers because they do not meet requirements I have for reliable software builds. However, I would be open to including support for non-MSBuild support provided the generation always occurs as part of the build, and not as an independent step. All properly-configured installations of the C# target will automatically regenerate the parsers following your modifications when you build the project, even if Visual Studio is not installed.

For ANTLR 4, follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs) for generating code, but skip the parts involving the optional Visual Studio extension. If you have trouble with any specific part, please create a new issue and describe the steps you tried and the system configuration you are working with.

For ANTLR 3, the instructions were created prior to migrating the project to GitHub, so they are [in Word format here](https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs/raw/master/ANTLRCSharpDocumentation.docx). Issues related to this documentation can be created on the [ANTLR 3 C# Target project on GitHub](https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs). **Important note (edit):** The documentation was also written prior to the creation of the [Antlr3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr3/3.5.0.3-alpha002) NuGet package. Installing this NuGet package using the NuGet package manager will automatically configure the project file, eliminating the need for steps 1.1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 in the documentation.